# Laravel-Auditing is not working without any errors

Tags: laravel, package, auditing

I've recently installed [this](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/9.0/auditable-configuration) package and configured everything with guide but some how it's not working!
By it's not working I mean it's not adding anything to database. I really don't know what is wrong with my configs but I've checked everything with guide 3 times and everything is correct but... I don't know

**config/audit.php:**

```
<?php

return [

    'enabled' => env('AUDITING_ENABLED', true),

    'implementation' => OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::class,

    'user' => [
        'morph_prefix' => 'user',
        'guards'       => [
            'web',
            'api',
        ],
    ],

    'resolver' => [
        'user'       => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UserResolver::class,
        'ip_address' => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\IpAddressResolver::class,
        'user_agent' => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UserAgentResolver::class,
        'url'        => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UrlResolver::class,
    ],

    'events' => [
        'created',
        'updated',
        'deleted',
        'restored',
        'gold_mailed' => 'goldMailed',
        'invited' => 'clientInvited',
    ],

    'strict' => false,

    'timestamps' => false,

    'threshold' => 0,

    'driver' => 'session',

    'drivers' => [
        'eloquent' => [
            'table'      => 'audits',
            'connection' => null,
        ],
    ],

    'console' => true,
];
```

**My model that I want to audit:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

use App\Models\Expansion;
use App\Models\Audit;

class Setting extends Model implements Auditable
{
    protected $table = 'settings';

    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;


    protected $fillable = [
      'expansion_id', 'season', 'advertiser_app', 'pvp_app', 'raid_app', 'version'
    ];

    protected $auditInclude = [
       'expansion_id', 'season', 'advertiser_app', 'pvp_app', 'raid_app', 'version'
   ];

    public function Expansion()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Expansion::class, 'id', 'expansion_id');
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('/setting' , 'Admin\SuperAdminController@saveSetting')->middleware('superadmin')->name('admin_save_setting');
```

Controller:

```
public function saveSetting(Request $request)
  {
    $sql = Setting::where('id', 1)->update([
      'expansion_id' => $request['expansion_id'],
      'season' => $request['season'],
      'advertiser_app' => $request['advertiser_app'],
      'pvp_app' => $request['pvp_app'],
      'raid_app' => $request['raid_app'],
      'version' => $request['version']
    ]);
    if ($sql) {
      toastr()->success('Settings successfully updated.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
    toastr()->error('Something went wrong!');
    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

I don't know what infos do you need but I think this is enough

I think my problem is with "driver" in config file , I don't know if that's correct or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**

Based on the controller code you showed, it didn't work because your code is being called using `Builder` style, and the package only works when it is called using `Eloquent` style.

[Documentation link](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/9.0/troubleshooting)
[image: Builder vs. Eloquent]

So, maybe you need to change your code to:

```
$setting = Setting::where('id', 1)->firstOrFail();
$setting->update([
  'expansion_id' => $request['expansion_id'],
  'season' => $request['season'],
  'advertiser_app' => $request['advertiser_app'],
  'pvp_app' => $request['pvp_app'],
  'raid_app' => $request['raid_app'],
  'version' => $request['version']
]);
```

Comment: yep I did this step

Comment: is the `audits` table already created? @AlirezaBehnamnik

Comment: yeah , everything is done exactly with guide

Comment: have you tried changing `'driver'` into `database`? @AlirezaBehnamnik

Comment: yeah , change both 'session' and 'eloquent' to 'database' but nothing happened -_-

Comment: can you please upload your code example for testing the audits? @AlirezaBehnamnik

Comment: should I add specific code for that? guide said I just need codes to my model and edit config/audit.php , let me share my controller code

Comment: @AlirezaBehnamnik check updated answer

Comment: thank you very much it worked! but now I have a problem , I will post it because it's long

Answer (score 0):

now I have another problem -_-

this is my controller:

```
$sql = Raid::findOrFail($request['id']);
$sql = $sql->update($request->all());
```

I have a array in my table , after update value will be like this:

```
"{\"Plate\":0,\"Cloth\":0,\"Mail\":0,\"Leather\":0}"
```

but it should be:

```
{"Plate":"0","Cloth":"0","Mail":"0","Leather":"0"}
```

so I will get an error
before this , I was updating like this and it was ok:

```
$sql = Raid::where('id', $request['id'])->update($request->all());
```

and this is my mode (traders and class_traders is fields that I have problem with):

```
    use SoftDeletes;

    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $table = 'raid';

    protected $dates = ['date_and_time','deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
      'admin_id', '....
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'bosses' => 'array',
        'traders' => 'array',
        'class_traders' => 'array',
        'boosters' => 'array',
    ];
```

Comment: Consider making it as another Stackoverflow's question so that other people can see it. Besides, you can only accept 1 answer.